# Variance of the supremum of a Gaussian process

Tags: pr.probability

Let $X_t$, $t \geq 0$, be a centered continuous Gaussian process. Is there a general, useful, bound on the variance of the supremum $\sup_{0\leq t \leq T} X_t$?

Answer (score 4):

By the [Borell--Tsirelson--Ibragimov--Sudakov inequality](https://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Ebiskup/PIMS/PDFs/lecture6.pdf) on concentration of the maximum of a centered Gaussian process, for $M:=\sup_{0\le t\le T} X_t$ and all real $x>0$ we have
$$P(|M-EM|>x)\le2 e^{-x^2/(2\sigma^2)},$$
where $\sigma^2:=\sup_{0\le t\le T}EX_t^2$. So, the variance of $M$ is
$$E(M-EM)^2=\int_0^\infty 2x\,dx\,P(|M-EM|>x)
\le\int_0^\infty 2x\,dx\,2 e^{-x^2/(2\sigma^2)}=4\sigma^2.$$

This bound on the variance of $M$ is obviously optimal up to a universal constant factor, because the variance of $M$ equals $\sigma^2$ if $X_t=X_0$ for all $t$.

Comment: Can one expect the optimal bound $\sigma^2$ (without the constant 4)?

Comment: @DmitriRozev : Good question. I do not know an answer to it, though.

Comment: @DimitriRosev : If your problem admits a bit more structure, you might want to have a look at the book 'Random fields and geometry' by Adler and Taylor (Springer).